# iOS adding a view with size of the total screen and rotate it when device rotates

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

Hi guys I am having an app that works fine as of now. I have a rootViewController and have a custom VC of size 500*500 presented over it, no problem till now, my UX folks want a loading screen of gray bg &  the size of the window - with a activity indicator, a label in the center is  and should rotate on device rotation.

**1. I tried adding a viewcontroller's view as subView of window and the rotation functions were never fired.**

**2. I tried adding a view as subview to window and tried rotating it manually, no luck either.**

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You need to make sure that your rootViewController is set up to rotate properly (i.e. the `shouldRotate` method returns `YES` and the supported interface orientations are set correctly for iOS 6.x).

Comment: Did that too, I suspected this issue and added shouldRotate and other rotation methods to almost all of my VC's :-( no luck.

Comment: You also verified that all orientations are supported in your App Settings?  Verified via breakpoints that the methods are being called in your root view controller?  Set up the root view controller to forward rotation events?

Comment: Yes all my VC's rotate properly and I am handling rotation in them.

Comment: So what is the problem then ? o,0 Just add your new controller as a child controller of one of the controllers in the hierarchy and add the view as a subview.

Comment: No problem in other VC's, the rotation delegates in the loading VC never get called. I will try to add it as a childVC.